# Divide a column depending on a row value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a calculation in Pandas that looks obvious, but after several tries I did not find how to do it correctly.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "a", 10.0],
                   ["A", "b", 12.0],
                   ["A", "c", 13.0],
                   ["B", "a", 5.0 ],
                   ["B", "b", 6.0 ],
                   ["B", "c", 7.0 ]])
```

The first column is a test name, the second column is a class, and third column gives a time. Each test is normally present in the table with the 3 classes.

This is the correct format to plot it like this:

```
sns.factorplot(x="2", y="0", hue="1", data=df,
               kind="bar")
```

So that for each test, I get a group of 3 bars, one for each class.

However I would like to change the dataframe so that each value in column 2 is not an absolute value, but a ratio compared to class "a".

So I would like to transform it to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "a", 1.0],
                   ["A", "b", 1.2],
                   ["A", "c", 1.3],
                   ["B", "a", 1.0],
                   ["B", "b", 1.2],
                   ["B", "c", 1.4]])
```

I am able to extract the series, change the index so that they match, do the computation, for example:

```
df_a = df[df[1] == "a"].set_index(0)
df_b = df[df[1] == "b"].set_index(0)
df_b["ratio_a"] = df_b[2] / df_a[2]
```

But this is certainly very inefficient, and I need to group it back to the format.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this with some index alignment.

```
df1 = df.set_index(['test', 'class'])
df1 / df1.xs('a', level='class')
```

But transform is better

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`groupby/transform('first')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine) to find the first value in each group:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "a", 10.0],
                   ["A", "b", 12.0],
                   ["A", "c", 13.0],
                   ["B", "b", 6.0 ],
                   ["B", "a", 5.0 ],
                   ["B", "c", 7.0 ]])
df = df.sort_values(by=[0,1])
df[2] /= df.groupby(0)[2].transform('first')
```

yields

```
   0  1    2
0  A  a  1.0
1  A  b  1.2
2  A  c  1.3
3  B  a  1.0
4  B  b  1.2
5  B  c  1.4
```

Comment: This is good. `df.groupby(0)[2].transform(lambda x: x/x.iloc[0])` should also be fine I suppose?

Comment: @JohnGalt: The "built-in" functions like `transform('first')` are Cythonized, so they run much faster than transforms with bespoke functions like `lambda x: x/x.iloc[0]`. But yes, it would produce the same result.

Comment: This looks good. To guaranty that "first" is the correct label, should I first sort the dataframe by column 1?

Comment: @Dric512: Yes -- if `a` is not always in the first row, you would need to sort: `df = df.sort_values(by=[0,1])` to use the groupby/transform above. Also note that the method above assumes the `a` row exists for each group.

Comment: @Dric512: Because of these issues, you may want to consider [Ted Petrou's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41000646/190597) instead.

Comment: Agreed, as in reality the class 'a' may not be the first one when sorted. But +1 anyway as the answer is really useful.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but I haven't seen the `transform("string")` syntax before - is "first" used this way here because it is available by [dispatching](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dispatching-to-instance-methods)?

Comment: @Ajean: Per [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns), "function names can also be strings. In order for a string to be valid it must be either implemented on GroupBy or available via dispatching". The available string names can be found from the [GroupBy method names shown here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id35).

Comment: Aha!  There it is, thank you. I originally went to look at the API [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform) and was left a little wanting...